# Jquery button onclick attribute not working

Tags: html, jquery

```
 $.get($querystudent, function(response)
    {
        tbodystudent.empty();
        console.log("Table TBODY Cleared!");
        var students = response.result;
        var $i = 0
        $.each(students, function(_,student)
        {
            $i = student.ID
            tbodystudent.append(
                $("<tr>").append(
                    $("<td>").text(student.FirstName),
                    $("<td>").text(student.MiddleName),
                    $("<td>").text(student.LastName),
                    $("<td>").text(student.CourseID),
                    $("<td>").text(student.YearLevel),
                    $("<input></input>").attr({'type':'button','class':'button is-primary is-small','id':$i, 'onclick': select($i)}).val("Select")          
                ),
            );

        });
    }, "json");
```

This is my current Jquery code that appends data to the tbody with attribute onclick trying to call a function select(),

```
    function select(x)
{
    console.log('Im Here! ', x)
}
```

Without clicking any button, the console is showing that the three buttons have been clicked already from the start of the page Onload.
[Console indicates that the function is called already with no buttons being clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FA8KQ.png)

Inspect also indicates that the onclick attribute was not added to the button attributes

Comment: It should be `'onclick': \`select(${$i})\`` Otherwise, you're using the return value of `select($i)`, which is undefined since you don't return anything from that function, and you're firing `select($i)` when you assign the attributes.

Comment: David is right, but even better is to use `.click()` or `.on('click', function(){ .. })` [jQuery event handler assignment](https://api.jquery.com/click/) after the `.attr()`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your idea, I've updated and let it works. You can check the below demo:

`'onclick': select($i)` -> `'onclick': 'select(' + $i + ')'`

`$("<input></input>")` -> `$("<button>")` : I'm still finding the reason why `$("<input>")` is not working

```js
const students = [{
    ID: 1,
    FirstName: 'A',
    MiddleName: 'B',
    LastName: 'C',
    CourseID: 1,
    YearLevel: 1
  },
  {
    ID: 2,
    FirstName: 'A',
    MiddleName: 'B',
    LastName: 'C',
    CourseID: 1,
    YearLevel: 1
  }, {
    ID: 3,
    FirstName: 'A',
    MiddleName: 'B',
    LastName: 'C',
    CourseID: 1,
    YearLevel: 1
  }
]

function select(x) {
  console.log('Im Here! ', x)
}

$.each(students, function(_, student) {
  $i = student.ID
  $('#tbodystudent').append(
    $("<tr>").append(
      $("<td>").text(student.FirstName),
      $("<td>").text(student.MiddleName),
      $("<td>").text(student.LastName),
      $("<td>").text(student.CourseID),
      $("<td>").text(student.YearLevel),
      $("<button>").attr({
        'type': 'button',
        'class': 'button is-primary is-small',
        'id': $i,
        'onclick': 'select(' + $i + ')'
      }).text("Select")
    ),
  );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">FirstName</th>
      <th scope="col">MiddleName</th>
      <th scope="col">LastName</th>
      <th scope="col">CourseID</th>
      <th scope="col">YearLevel</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbodystudent">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Changing the <input> into <button> with the combination of the new onclick attribute worked for me but changing but into <input> doesn't work. It seems that the <input> is causing the issue together with my first attribute onclick.

Comment: @MarkBryanDeGuzman yes, you should let it works first and find out the reason later.